# allow read access to firebase only when limitation params passed

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I have Firebase database and my app read data with pagination. For pagination I use orderByIndex.
`https://<firebaseurl>/list.json?orderBy="index"&startAt=1&limitToFirst=100`.
I want to restrict to read whole data, and allow only read it with pagination.
How I can configure rules to allow `read` only when GET params `orderBy,startAt,limitToFirst` are given?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way in Firebase's security rules to allow a read on condition that a certain query parameter is met.

The typical way to solve this would be to have a separate node where you ensure those conditions are met when writing the data. For example in your code a node called `last100` would be a good idea.